Does $\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{\cos\frac{x}{n}}{x^{n^{2}}+1}=1-x$ for $-1<x\le1$?
I was just typing random things into Desmos and I came across this. WolframAlpha didn't give a closed form for the numerator or denominator and I don't recall coming across any formula like this before. Here is my attempt to solve it analytically:
$$\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{\cos\frac{x}{n}}{x^{n^{2}}+1}=\exp\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\ln\frac{\cos\frac{x}{n}}{x^{n^{2}}+1}$$
As you can see, I didn't really get anywhere. I also tried to expand different parts into their series expansions but it didn't seem to help. Is my conjecture that $\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{\cos\frac{x}{n}}{x^{n^{2}}+1}=1-x$ on $-1<x\le1$ true?

I doubt it. Looking at $x=1/2$ and denoting the product term by $a_n$, we have $|1-a_n|<10^{-4}$ for $n\ge 36$. Yet the partial product yields $\prod_{1\le n\le 36} a_n\approx 0.526945 $, a value that is unchanged if we increase the upper limit to $100$ instead of $36$. This is not particularly close to $0.5$, and given the fast rate of convergence, I doubt it can get there, as $0.5/0.526945\approx 94.89%$. So, I think it's close to linear, but not exactly linear on $[0,1]$.
